# Black screen while gaming after Nvidia GeForce GTX 650 driver update (v.457.51)

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

After updating the driver on Nvidia GeForce GTX 650 to v.457.51 (release date 02-Dec-2020) via GeForce Experience while gaming after 5-15mins the screen goes black, and there must be a restart so the PC can work normally again. Sometimes there is a sound loss when the screen is black, but sometimes there isn't and the sound of the game can be heard.

The weird thing is that the screen goes black **only** while gaming, and not while working other stuff. And this wasn't the case before the update, but had to update the driver because most of the games couldn't be run (they requested driver update).

I have tried Uninstalling the Device via Device Manager, restarting the PC and then reinstalling the latest driver, but so far no luck. The GPU is not overheating while in-game (have tracked with Speccy), or anything like that.

I have no other ideas what to try and what to do so I can fix this issue.

Comment: If NVIDIA managed to screw up their latest version, return to the version that worked for you.

Comment: Can't to that, `... but had to update the driver because most of the games couldn't be run (they requested driver update).`

Comment: If the games worked before, the problem with them asking for updates can probably be forced.

Answer (score 0):

NVidia had a few glitchy drivers this year.
Update to something newer. Don't rely on Experience, go directly to NVidia - https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/drivers/
Current is 460.89

There is mileage to be had in not installing Experience [or any of the other bloatware that comes with it] & installing the drivers only.